# How to 'insert' data into database via VB

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, vba

Stuggling a bit here. Trying to develop the code to link user input into my database, in the form of a book record. for example the user would be asked to enter their name address etc. But the code I have used does not seem to execute because I continually get the same error.

```
Line 12:         Dim con As New SqlConnection
Line 13:         Dim inscmd As New SqlCommand
Line 14:         con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Database.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
Line 15:         con.Open()
Line 16:         inscmd.CommandText = ("insert into booking values('" + txtfirstname.Text + "', " + txtSurname.Text + "', " + txtAddressline1.Text + "', " + txtAddressline2.Text + "', " + txtPostcode.Text + "', " + txtTime.Text + "', " + txtPeople.Text + "', " + txtDropoff1.Text + "', " + txtDropoff2.Text + "', " + txtDropoffpost.Text + "")
```

It is line 14 that contains the error but I dont know why. This is my code;

```
Protected Sub btnsubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles  btnsubmit.Click
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim inscmd As New SqlCommand
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Database.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
    con.Open()
    inscmd.CommandText = ("insert into booking values('" + txtfirstname.Text + "', " + txtSurname.Text + "', " + txtAddressline1.Text + "', " + txtAddressline2.Text + "', " + txtPostcode.Text + "', " + txtTime.Text + "', " + txtPeople.Text + "', " + txtDropoff1.Text + "', " + txtDropoff2.Text + "', " + txtDropoffpost.Text + "")
    Print(inscmd.CommandText)
    inscmd.Connection = con
    inscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    inscmd.Parameters.Clear()

    MsgBox("Your booking has been successfully")
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error? Is the connection string in your web.config actually called "Database.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1" ?

Comment: ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> This is what it says in my web config file?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help you ( insert your code where need to  )

```
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim myConString As String = getSQLString() ' GET YOUR CON String
```

' my function looks like this when returned

"Server=ServerExactLocationPath;Database=DataBase;User Id=UserName;Password=Password;"

```
        Dim objcommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        'con.ConnectionString = myConString

        With objcommand
            .Connection = con
            Dim cmdText As String = ""
            cmdText = "Insert into SitesStatus (SiteNumber,StatusName,Date,ByUser) values ('" & site & "','" & status & "','" & System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "','" & dbUiInitials & "')"
        'PUT YOUR INSERT ABOVE

         .CommandText = cmdText
        End With
        con.ConnectionString = myConString
        con.Open()
        objcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
      End Try
 Return Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into booking values('" + txtfirstname.Text + "', " + txtSurname.Text + "', " + txtAddressline1.Text + "', " + txtAddressline2.Text + "', " + txtPostcode.Text + "', " + txtTime.Text + "', " + txtPeople.Text + "', " + txtDropoff1.Text + "', " + txtDropoff2.Text + "', " + txtDropoffpost.Text + "
```

should be

```
insert into booking values('" + txtfirstname.Text + "', '" + txtSurname.Text + "', '" + txtAddressline1.Text + "', '" + txtAddressline2.Text + "', '" + txtPostcode.Text + "', " + txtTime.Text + "', '" + txtPeople.Text + "', '" + txtDropoff1.Text + "', '" + txtDropoff2.Text + "', '" + txtDropoffpost.Text + "')"
```

Comment: please post <connectionstrings> portion of your web.xml

Comment: <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.BookingModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.BookingModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.BookingModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>

Comment: <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

Comment: so Database.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1 sould be replaced either with DatabaseEntities or ConnectionString

Comment: I have tried both of these and neither work. this is the error i am receiving  "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: remove con.close from  inscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    inscmd.Parameters.Clear() as you are closing con after msgbox again

Answer (score 0):

You should use the connection string wizard in the Project Settings window. Then try the test connection button, Make sure the type of the setting is ConnectionString
You should be able to get the connection string using this syntax if things are set up right.

```
con.ConnectionString = my.Settings.Database1ConnectionString1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO user_account_details" & _
                "(lastname,firstname,middlename,usertype,reg_date_time,status)" & _
                " VALUES ( " & _
                " '" & txtLName.Text & "', " & _
                " '" & txtFName.Text & "' , " & _
                " '" & txtMName.Text & "' , " & _
                " '" & cboUserType.Text & "' , " & _
                " '#" & Now & "#', " & _
                " 'Inactive' " & _
                ")"
```